# Developing Windows 10 widget app always on desktop

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-10

How does one create a desktop application for Windows 10 that is always on the Desktop?

Like Widgets behaved. That is, having "always on top" when you go to "Show desktop" but not on top of other windows all the time.

So the application behaves like a desktop background if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Here's how you could achieve it

Learn how to use WinForms or UWP so that you can create the different widgets with a user-friendly UI. Microsoft has an additional tool called Microsoft Blend, you can create good user interfaces with it.

Read about C# and how it works. You can program the functionality to make the Widgets stay on your desktop and not disappear when clicking the bar on the bottom right of your taskbar.

You might need to google a lot of things until you are ready to do it.

### Look at examples

[WinWidgets](https://www.github.com/beyluta/winwidgets) is an open-source widget project hosted on GitHub by me. You can clone the repository and take a look at how it works.

It covers your requirements and I'm sure you can learn how to do it on your own if you give it a shot.

[image]